# Meaning of an expression about a movie

Tags: meaning, cinema

I was reading an intro about the movie *Sense and Sensibility* on IMDB.
I am not getting this sentence mentioned below.

> The two eldest daughters are the **title opposites**

What does **title opposite** is supposed to mean? 
What exactly is meant here?

Comment: My guess: it's a typo and should be "total opposites".

Comment: or the sisters totally ***lack*** sense / sensibility.

Comment: I really hope that's a typo, not another phrasal verb I have to be aware of!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That makes sense! Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the two sisters represent the two traits in the title. One represents 'sense' (ie the head ruling the heart, and being 'sensible' - that's Elinor) and the other represents 'sensibility' (which in Austen's time meant 'sensitivity' - in other words, emotional - that's Marianne).

A [short article on 'decrypting the title'](https://www.wondriumdaily.com/jane-austens-sense-and-sensibility-decrypting-the-title/) says:

> Then, as now, the word sense meant reason, rationality, and wisdom. It
> signaled good sense, or common sense. But in Austen’s day, the word
> sensibility was different. It meant sensitivity or emotional
> receptivity. Throughout the novel, Austen couples the word sense with
> ideas of goodness, honor, and duty. Sense has a straightforwardly
> positive valence here. But the word sensibility is yoked to more
> complicated adjectives in the novel: potent sensibility; strong
> sensibility; and affectionate sensibility.

The same article doesn't agree that the two traits as shown in Sense and Sensibility are actually opposites, as is implied by the term 'title opposites'. But it's a common understanding of the book and the two lead characters.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanaiton.